# php website with multiple pages and different mod_rewrite clean urls from same script

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello and sorry if this is already answered, I've searched for days and haven't found an answer or know if its a good idea.

I'm creating a site with PHP scripts that can return different pages. I'm also using mod_rewrite now to create clean URLs. For example, I have a script **myscript.php** and in it it would return **page1**, **page2**, or **page3** depending on some parameters. That works.

The url would always be **mysite.com/myscript.php** but the output would be 3 different pages.

Then I apply mod_rewrite, and the url is now **mysite.com/publicname**. Great, but now the problem is I want the three different pages to display as **mysite.com/publicname1**, **mysite.com/publicname2**, **mysite.com/publicname3**.

Since this requires pushing? a different URL to the browser I must use a redirect to another script of this name? Is there a better way or best practice to doing this? What are the browser and device support issues with this? Should I design my site differently that I don't do any redirects, or are PHP Location: redirects well supported and ok in building a site?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is not really clear what you ask: you can create rewriting rules that "map" arbitrary requested urls to your script `myscript.php` and append a parameter that allows you to return the page indicated by the request url. But there are no urls you have to "push" somewhere. If you ask about links (html anchors) which you embed into some page, so that the user can click them, then you just send them using a hard coded html page or a script which echos the urls. No magic required there.

Comment: Sorry its unclear. I mean the user is on a page and submits a form to mysite.com/page and depending on what the input is, they get a page back, but the url also changes to mysite/page1 or mysite/page2. In order to change url it has to have a redirect?

Comment: If that's all, then all you need is a redirection rule that sends an "external redirect" (`R=301`).

Comment: Right, so user submits form to /page, this gets mod_rewrite to /myscript.php. Depending on input, myscript.php returns a redirect to /page1, /page2, or /page3, then mod_rewrite would again direct those requests to the appropriate script(s). Is this a best practice?

Comment: Sure, that's common practice. Maybe you can even limit yourself to apaches own means to send the first redirect header by rewriting rules. The second rewriting most probably will be internally, so instead of sending a redirection header you internally rewrite the request to a script of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to implement routing, with a single front controller. This is most often seen in the MVC design pattern.

There are lots of MVC framework that do this out of the box - CodeIgniter or Yii would be a good start.

If you do want to roll your own, look for articles about implement the front controller pattern e.g. http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/.

Comment: Hi Blowski, I didn't have the terminology of front controller. Yes we want to roll our own, our site will be very custom and we've investigated lots of frameworks already. I'm still trying to understand if I can return multiple differen URLs from the same URL request. User submits form to /page and get returned /page1 or /page2 do I need to do a redirect to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to route URLs to specific actions and render different content to the user, then MVC is really going to help you. However, it's very complicated to get right, and certainly not something that can be explained in a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I appreciate that, I just want to know how/if I can "push" a different URL back to the user than they requested this way. Is a header redirect the only answer and is it ok/best practice to do this?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'push' back. You can return different content based on URL parameters. In pseudo code that might look like `return render_post($_GET['post_id']);`. You can use mod_rewrite to mask the GET variable, and you can use anything as the GET variable. But you're really reinventing the wheel by doing anything complicated with routing.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have nothing to do with URL rewriting, they do not see it and do not care about what is going on in you server, all they know (and should know), is that when they request a URL (with parameters or not), they got a response (html, JS, CSS, images ... etc).

so either your 3 urls (mysite.com/publicname1,mysite.com/publicname2,mysite.com/publicname3) are pointing to the same file or different files are your design and that is apache http mod_rewrite who is taking care about that.

So you can do something like this if you want the 3 url to redirect to the same file:

```
RewriteRule ^publicname1$ myscript.php?page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^publicname2$ myscript.php?page=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^publicname3$ myscript.php?page=3 [L]
```

Or more simply:

```
RewriteRule ^publicname([0-9]+)$ myscript.php?page=$1 [L]
```

but this realy depends on what you are trying to do